# Codeigniter AJAX data returns empty

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, codeigniter

So I'm not exactly proficient in using codeiginiter but I've been working with it for a while now.

I'm trying to make an SQL query to search for books in the database, but the ajax always returns empty.

I echoed a few dummy strings to make sure that a proper connection is established between the controller and the view, and I made sure the SQL query itself works, but I don't understand why this still happens.

This is the javascript:

```
    $('#search').on("keyup", function() {
search = $(this).val();
console.log("Search Term: " + search);
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + "vault/quick_search",
    data: {search_term:search},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
      console.log("Result: " + data);
    }, 
    error: function(data)
    {
        alert("?");
    }
});
});
```

This is the controller:

```
      function quick_search()
    {
       $search = $this->input->post('search_term');
       $result = $this->vault_instance->quick_search($search);
       echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

This is the model:

```
      function quick_search($search_term)
 {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%harr%' OR author LIKE '%harr%'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array;
 }
```

NOTE: sorry for the poor editing, this is my first time asking a question.
Also, in the model I used "harr" as a test, I understand it's not the search term itself, it still returns empty

Comment: But you did good editing of your code. But wait for the hints.

Comment: Welcome! Are you developing on your local machine? Some browsers have security measures in place that make Ajax tricky. Are there any errors/warnings in your browser's dev console?

Comment: Did you check if you see any errors in your console

Comment: I think u have issue here `return $query->result_array;` this should be `return $query->result_array();`

Comment: Yes, I'm working on my local machine. There aren't really any warnings or errors. I've done many other AJAX calls; they worked just fine. This one isn't, however.

Comment: Thank you @devpro :D your solution worked. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I have also posted in answer chk and also accept it will help to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
return $query->result_array;
```

**With**:

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Becuase `result_array()` is a function which return you result into array format.

Answer (score 0):

What is the collation you using for your database column? If not utf8_general_ci try to change to it.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this works, but... try to change the datatype in your `$.ajax` call to `jsonp` (instead of `json`).

Comment: That will not change anything

Comment: The AJAX returns an error now. Is there anything else I need to modify for jsonp to work?

Comment: @Sushanth `jsonp` helps if you're not getting AJAX data returned due to the Same-Domain policy restriction.